# Win bat file: How to get the result of FIND into a new variable?

Tags: windows, pdf, batch-file, pdftk

The pdftk tool "dump_data" function can be used to deliver meta information about a pdf, including the number of pages. The following command...

```
pdftk test.pdf dump_data | find "NumberOfPages"
```

...outputs the full data dump line, for example:

```
"Number of pages: 32"
```

How can I get the count value (32 in the above case) into a new variable for further processing in the bat file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the format of the line is fixed and matches the one you've shown, you could try something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
>testfile ECHO Number of pages: 32
FOR /F "delims=: tokens=2" %%A IN ('TYPE testfile ^| FIND "Number of pages"') DO SET /A pagenum=%%A
ECHO %pagenum%
```

Outputs:

```
32
```

Naturally, `>testfile ECHO ...` line is just for testing purposes, and the `TYPE testfile` part of the `FOR` loop should be replaced by your `pdftk test.pdf dump_data`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%v IN (`pdftk test.pdf dump_data ^| find "Number of pages"`) DO (
    FOR /F "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%i IN ("%%v") DO set NBPAGES=%%j
)
```

Note that you have to use two `%` in front of every variables  in the above example if you are using it in a batch file. If you are running it directly from the console, use only one `%`.